# apollo subscription setting with subscribeToMore query - updateQuery not respecting key args

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, hasura

I'm trying to achieve a real time connection using Apollo client in my react app.
I've set up my queries and type policies as below however, I'm failing to achieve my goal where only items that fits in to the filter gets add / updated.

**Type Policy**

```
typePolicies: {
      Query: {
        fields: {
          process: {
            ...offsetLimitPagination(["where", "order_by"]),
            read(existing = []) {
              return uniqueByRef(existing);
            },
          },
          process_stream: {
            ...offsetLimitPagination(["where", "order_by"]),
            read(existing = []) {
              return uniqueByRef(existing);
            },
          },
...
```

**Loader Component**

```
const { data, loading, error, fetchMore, subscribeToMore } = useQuery(
    QUERY_PROCESS,
    {
      variables: { ...filters, limit },
      onCompleted(data) {
        setTotalLength(data.process_aggregate?.aggregate?.count || 0);
      },
      onError(error) {
        addAlert({ message: "Cannot load process items", type: "failure" });
        console.log(error);
      },
    }
  );

  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }


  const subFilter = {
    _and: filters.where?._and.filter(p => !Object.hasOwn(p, "deleted")),
  };

  subscribeToMore({
    document: STREAM_PROCESS,
    variables: {
      where: subFilter,
      cursor: { initial_value: { updated_at: cursor }, ordering: "ASC" },
    },
    updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
      setCursor(new Date().toISOString());
      if (!subscriptionData.data) return prev;
      const newFeedItem = subscriptionData.data.process_stream;
      const existing = prev.process.filter(
        p => !newFeedItem.find(i => i.id == p.id)
      );
      const filterDeleted = [...newFeedItem, ...existing].filter(
        p => !p.deleted
      );
      return Object.assign({}, prev, {
        process: uniqueById(filterDeleted),
      });
    },
  });
```

With the updateQuery, the where key args is not respected which means I even updates that I do not want to be merged gets merged.
I think I can apply a custom filter function inside the updateQuery method, however it's not really what I want to do..
Without the updateQuery, it works fine except that it only updates existing items in the cache and not merge new items.

I've tried writing a merge function, in both stream and normal query type policy but with no avail.
If any folks can help me out of this hell, I'll be in your debt forever..
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To someone who is trying to achieve the similar goal..

I found the problem with my code.
It was not because of any cache beahaviour but a mere mistake of not putting the subscribeToMore function in useEffect hook with filters dependency.
The problem was that the subscription was made before the filters were initiallised.

The working code is as below

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const subFilter = {
      _and: filters.where?._and.filter(p => !Object.hasOwn(p, "deleted")),
    };

    const unsubscribe = subscribeToMore({
      document: SUB_CONTACTS,
      variables: {
        where: subFilter,
        cursor: {
          initial_value: { updated_at: cursor },
          ordering: "ASC",
        },
      },
      updateQuery: (previous, { subscriptionData }) => {
        setCursor(new Date().toISOString());
        if (!subscriptionData.data) return previous;
        const previousData = cloneDeep(previous.contacts);
        const newFeedItem = subscriptionData.data.contacts_stream;
        const existing = previousData.filter(
          p => !newFeedItem.find(i => i.id == p.id)
        );
        const filterDeleted = [...newFeedItem, ...existing].filter(
          p => !p.deleted
        );
        return Object.assign({}, previous, {
          contacts: filterDeleted,
        });
      },
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [filters.where._and]);
```

With the above setup, you get newly added items that fit in to the filter as well as detect deletion (by not deleting first but setting a boolean value to trigger the subscription and then deleting)

My next problem to solve is the situation when the value of data is altered to a status where it does not fit in the filter as it does not invoke subscription

Hope this helps someone trying to set up a real time connection utilising the cache as well.